# Pausing and restarting a secondary, synchronous thread

Tags: swift, multithreading

Using `DispatchQueue`, I can create a new thread, which I can run synchronously or asynchronously with the main thread:

```
import Foundation

let thread = DispatchQueue(label: "thread")

thread.sync {
    // Code here...
}
```

What I have been trying to do is to run the separate thread to a certain point, pause it, continue running the main thread, and then go back the the secondary thread. Is that possible?

Here is an illustration:

```
import Foundation

let thread = DispatchQueue(label: "thread")

thread.sync {
    print("Thread Started")
    // Pause Thread
    print("Thread Ended")
}
print("Before Thread Ended")
// Start Thread
print("After Thread Ended")
```

The desired output:

```
Thread Started
Before Thread Ended
Thread Ended
After Thread Ended
```

Comment: You need to coordinate them with some type of shared lock.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem before - you can use `dispatch_semaphore` to pause and resume a thread.

`dispatch_semaphore_wait` decrements the semaphore which has a value of 0 by default and you can specify how much time you want it to wait including `DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER` and `dispatch_semaphore_signal` increments its value back to 0 which then resumes your thread. Hope that helps!

Example (you can try this code in Playgrounds):

```
 // Main thread
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value:0)
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "Queue")

//Asynchronously execute some code on a separate thread
queue.async {
    print("Code executed before pause")

    // This will pause the thread
    semaphore.wait(timeout: .distantFuture)

    print("Woohoo - Code executed after resuming the semaphore")
}

// Some sort of trigger - I am putting the thread to sleep for 5 sec as next line will otherwise execute straight away    
sleep(5)

// On main thread resume the semaphore
semaphore.signal()
```

Comment: Can you expand on this, maybe with some example code? I have messed around with those before, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Edited my answer - see example above.

Comment: This almost works, but If I do anything that takes to long inside of the other thread, simulated by `sleep(1)`, the code after the block runs before I want it to. Remember, I want this to run in a synchronous manner.